# How to access ES6 module variable by name (from the module itself)

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, webpack

In a webpack environment I've an ES6 module that define a variable:

```
let my_var1 = 0
// other vars follow
```

Then in the same module I have a setter function for this variable but I'd like to build it as follow:

```
export const set_var(name, value) => {
    // set "value" as new value for "name" variable of this module
}
```

What I want to do is to reference the variable inside the module **by name**, so externally call something like `set_var('my_var1', 5)`

There's a way to access the "module" object? Something like the window object, but for the module.

Comment: Just  *why* would you want to do that?

Comment: No, this is not possible. You can access exported variables by name through a module object, but you cannot set them.

Comment: _"Something like the window object ..."_ You could not do that with `window` either, because `let` doesn't create a property. Why don't you create an object in the first place?

Comment: In facts I moved to an object and I skipped the problem (this is also more clean probably).
As ES6 modules exports as read only and I need to store global data I tried that way first.

Answer (score 1):

You can instead refer to an object within the module, and then set the value of a key in that object (aka `my_var1`). then you can get the `my_var1` back with a getter:

```
let moduleObject = {
    my_var1: 0,
    my_var2: 5,
    ...
}

export const set_var = (varName, value) => moduleObject[varName] = value
export const get_var = (varName) => moduleObject[varName]
```

Comment: Please include a brief explanation instead of just posting code.

Answer (score 0):

No, this is not possible.

You can access exported variables by name through a module object, but you cannot set them.
You could not do that with window either, because let doesn't create a property.